# Access objects without pipe or ngfor in angular2

Tags: json, ajax, angular

Lets say that i have the following data asymmetrical array

```
 [{'name':'user','password':'123'},{'title':'officer','grade':'5','age':'5'}]
```

from an ajax request that maps it

```
return this._http.get(url).map( res => res.json() );
```

and i want to access it in angular2 html template, i directly know what each block corresponds to and it's technically not an array that you'd loop.

Is there a method in angular to access the data without using a pipe or ngFor?

currently i'm using a really dirty method by slicing ngFor then using the dictionary data

```
<div *ngFor="let  i of element| slice:0:1">
<p> {{element.name}} </p>
<p> {{element.pass}} </p>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let  i of element| slice:1:2">
<p> {{element.title}}</p>
...
```

is there a simpler way with less setup to do this, because i keep encountering hundres of exceptions and i can't find a simple documented way to access JSON objects without the overhead setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to guard null values if you get the data async

```
{{element && element[0].name}}
{{element && element[0].pass}}
{{element && element[1].title}}
```

Comment: does this apply to [[{}]{}] kind of structure? with {{element && element[0][1].title}}

Comment: and yes that technique also works, can you please explain or link the documentation for this?

Comment: Not sure what documentation you're looking for. The problem is that Angular tries to resolve that binding expression before the data arrived from your async `this._http.get()`. The code in my answer just returns `null` if `element` is `null` and `element[...]....` otherwise. This is basic JavaScript code. Nothing special here. `&&` is short-circuiting. When `element == null` then the part after `&&` is not evaluated at all.